# onkeyup and onkeydown interfering when interleaving presses and releases

Tags: javascript, events, onkeydown, onkeyup

The sequence

1. hold a key other than <kbd>Shift</kbd> down (say <kbd>Alt</kbd>),
2. hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> down,
3. release the key held since step 1,
4. release <kbd>Shift</kbd>,

results in leaving the "other key" colored, just like the `= 'none'` line didn't run for it.

Indeed, here's the GIF showing the behavior corresponding to the 4 actions above:

[image]

As you can see, the "Alt up" message is not printed, but trust me that I'm releasing <kbd>Alt</kbd> between holding down <kbd>Shifrt</kbd> and releasing <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

---

And now that I'm trying on another system <kbd>Shift</kbd> is not unique, I can get the same with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (the other key being for instance one of the 4 arrows).

---

Why is that? Is it unavoidable?

```js
window.onkeydown = listenKeyDown;
window.onkeyup = listenKeyUp;

function listenKeyDown(e) {
  console.log(e.key + " down")
  if (e.altKey) {
    document.getElementById('alt').style.background = '#00ff00';
  }
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    document.getElementById('ctrl').style.background = '#00ff00';
  }
  if (e.shiftKey) {
    document.getElementById('shift').style.background = '#00ff00';
  }
  let elem = document.getElementById(e.key);
  if (elem && !e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey) {
    elem.style.background = '#00ff00';
  }
}

function listenKeyUp(e) {
  console.log(e.key + " up")
  if (e.altKey) {
    document.getElementById('alt').style.background = 'none';
  }
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    document.getElementById('ctrl').style.background = 'none';
  }
  if (e.shiftKey) {
    document.getElementById('shift').style.background = 'none';
  }
  let elem = document.getElementById(e.key);
  if (elem && !e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey) {
    document.getElementById(e.key).style.background = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="alt">Alt</div>
<div id="ctrl">Ctrl</div>
<div id="shift">Shift</div>
<div id="End">End</div>
<div id="Home">Start</div>
<div id="ArrowUp">Up</div>
<div id="ArrowLeft">Left</div>
<div id="ArrowDown">Down</div>
<div id="ArrowRight">Right</div>
<ol>
  <li>Hold down a key (listed above, but other than Shift),</li>
  <li>Hold Shift down</li>
  <li>Release the key of step 1</li>
  <li>Release Shift</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify which keys are pressed by using a `Set`.

Also, avoid setting CSS dynamically on the element. Use classes for styling.

```js
const pressedKeys = new Set();

window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
window.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);

function handleKeyDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  pressedKeys.add(e.key);
  update();
}

function handleKeyUp(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  pressedKeys.delete(e.key);
  update();
}

function update(e) {
  for (let key of document.querySelectorAll('.key')) {
    key.classList.toggle('pressed', pressedKeys.has(key.dataset.key));
  }
}
```

```css
.pressed {
  background: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="key" data-key="Alt">Alt</div>
<div class="key" data-key="Control">Ctrl</div>
<div class="key" data-key="Shift">Shift</div>
<div class="key" data-key="End">End</div>
<div class="key" data-key="Home">Start</div>
<div class="key" data-key="ArrowUp">Up</div>
<div class="key" data-key="ArrowLeft">Left</div>
<div class="key" data-key="ArrowDown">Down</div>
<div class="key" data-key="ArrowRight">Right</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the improved solution, but this still doesn't solve the problem: if I hold down Alt, hold down Shift, release Alt, release Shift, I end up with Alt being colored. (On Chromium, just in case that's affecting anything.)

Comment: @Enlico in my snippet above, Alt and Shift are treated as completely separate actions.

Comment: @Enlico because you press Alt, you are moving focus away, be sure to prevent the default behavior o the key like I demonstrated.

Comment: I get the described behavior with your snippet as well, indeed.

Comment: Good advise of better coding, but this still doesn't address the main problem I'm showing.